# How to correctly create an HTML form which spans multiple pages

Tags: html, forms

Is it acceptable (in a standard's sense) to have a form which can span multiple pages? For example, I am making a shopping form, and on the main form are mugs and tshirts. However, I need to make it so the user can choose a color of a t shirt. Now, I could either add radio buttons to the small thumbnail of the tshirts, or I could make the t shirt image link to a larger page where they could see the image better, and provide radio buttons there since the differences in color stand out more. I somewhat prefer the latter. Would the process be to make the main page form, then have a second form on the subpage for the tshirt, and use url strings? Is there a way of passing HTML form variables "across" pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this by exposing and hiding divs that would represent the 'pages' .. toss in some ajax for updating in response to clicks, and you don't need multiple pages

Comment: you indicated you might want to show expanded information about a t-shirt if the user clicked a thumb nail . .if you can download everything at page load time, then you can fetch details on clicks and stuff into divs .. all before doing any form submits .. jQuery could really help you out with all of this

Comment: (damn uneditable comments) i meant to say ".if you canNOT download everything at page load time"

Comment: @scott: good call. question - i've been meaning to learn ajax/jquery, but now that i think about it, why do i need ajax at all? couldn't jquery just hide divs/show them based on clickage?